# Grails 3.1.5 dont produces jar file

Tags: grails, jar, executable-jar, grails-3.1

In version to 3.1.5, the command "package" not produces a jar file in "project/build/libs"

I ran a simple "create-app" and "package" with versions 3.0.9 and 3.1.5. Only the first produces a jar file. No error appears in both.

Someone knows how I create a executable JAR, in version 3.1.5?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.1.5/guide/gettingStarted.html#deployingAnApplication) states...

> If you prefer not to operate a separate Servlet container then you can
>   simply run the Grails WAR file as a regular Java application.

And then provides the following example:

```
grails war
java -Dgrails.env=prod -jar build/libs/mywar-0.1.war
```

So basically, the generated war file *is* a jar file.

Comment: Ok, but the difference is that the war is not executable. I have to run from the command line. @Emmanuel

Comment: Are you referring to some kind of association the OS's file manager has with jar files? For example, if I recall, on Windows double-clicking on a jar file runs it (with javaw, or something like that).

Comment: You can try changing the file extension from war to jar. It's basically the same thing.